# Django db migration stops working with "Meta" class

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to create a Django application, and I have a class like this in my `models.py` file:

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField(db_column = "DisplayName", max_length = 200)
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations myApp`, everything works as expected, and a migration file for the class is created.

The problem happens if the class in the model defines a `Meta` class as well:

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField(db_column = "DisplayName", max_length = 200)
    class Meta:
        app_label = "something"
```

Now, if I run the `makemigrations` command, I get a "no changes detected" message, and no migration file is generated:

```
> python manage.py makemigrations myApp
No changes detected in app 'myApp'
```

Please note that this was just an example, and the problem happens also if I run the command for the first time on a class with a `Meta` class defined, or if I delete the previously generated migration files.

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and Django 1.9.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have this in the Meta class do you?

```
managed = False
```

Comment: no, I get this problem even just with the "app_label" like in the example I made...